# change title of viewcontroller which is on UItabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have a UItabbacController with 6 tabs. My "More" tab contains 2 UIviewcontrollers. How to change title of one UIViewcontrolleller which will be showing in Morenavigationcontroller.

Initially that view controller title is "registration". But after logged in i have to change to "profile". 
Please help me ..thanks

- Edit

I have only one nib file and one ProfileViewController class and one ProfileView Class.

After logged in am just changing the title of one viewcontroller. that tableview cell text always showing "registration" only. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

In ViewDidLoad method of First view

```
 self.title = @"registration";
```

In ViewDidLoad method of Second view

```
self.title = @"profile";
```

All the Best

Comment: Both view are loading from same Interface builder file. so what to do ?

Comment: you will be having two view class.Change in both class files of viewdidload method.

Comment: i dont have two view class. I have only one nib file and one ProfileViewController class and one ProfileView Class.After logged in am just changing the title of one viewcontroller. that tableview cell text always showing "registration" only. thanks for all ur replies..

Comment: i think i posted question in a wrong way. i want to change the cell text  in "More Tableview".

Answer (score 2):

You can actually just do (in your ViewController subclasses ViewDidLoad):

```
self.title = @"Title";
```